# Jquery Mobile Needed Absolute Path?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I built an web-app using the the JQuery Mobile multi page template
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

It looked fine on HTC Desire HD, iPhone, iPad but not on my friends Samsung and HTC Desire.
After multiple code tweeks I realised if i changed all my relative paths to absolute paths it worked fine.

Do I need to link every object I build using JQM in this manner or is there something inside the head tag I can add??

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with relative paths. see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Refactor:-navigation-paths

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I saw this link, I just thought someone might have resolved it, or found a workaround for it. I guess not. Thanks